# Реализуйте набор готовых к использованию функций для arr.filter:

Tags: javascript

Реализуйте набор готовых к использованию функций для arr.filter:
`notInArray([...])` – значение не находится в данном массиве.

Они должны использоваться таким образом:
`arr.filter(notInArray([1,2,3]))` – выбирает только те элементы,
которые не совпадают ни с одним из элементов массива

Пример:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true, undefined, NaN];
console.log(arr.filter(notInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true]))); // [undefined, NaN]
```

Мой код:

```
const notInArray = arr => {
    return function(element, i, array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr.includes(array[i])) {
                array.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        return array;
    };
};
```

Проверку не проходит.

Comment: Если бы вы написали такую фильтрацию прямо внутри метода `filter()`, у вас бы проблемы возникли? Если нет, то по сути нужно будет просто эту функцию вынести за пределы.

Comment: даже не читая кода просто по `array.splice` можно сказать что функция неправильная.  Фильтрующая функция не должна ничего менять в массиве, она должна вернуть `true` или `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Исправляем ошибки в вашем коде:

Функции **notInArray** достаточно вернуть функцию, принимающую один аргумент(это будет текущий элемент фильтруемого массива), остальные не нужны(в данном примере).

В возвращаемой фукнции необходимо делать проверку, сущестует ли текущий элемент массива в массиве исключений. Если существует, вернуть **false**, иначе **true**.

```js
const notInArray = arr => elem => !arr.includes(elem);

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true, undefined, NaN];
console.log(arr.filter(notInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true])))
console.log(arr.filter(notInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, undefined])))
console.log(arr.filter(notInArray([4, 5, 6, 7, NaN])))
```

Если запись в одну строку сложна, то ниже полное описание функции с трансформацией

```js
const notInArray = arr => elem => !arr.includes(elem);
//
const notInArray = arr => elem => {
  return !arr.includes(elem);
}
//
const notInArray = arr => {
  return elem => {
    return !arr.includes(elem);
  }
}
//
const notInArray = arr => {
  return elem => {
    if (arr.includes(elem)) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
//
const notInArray = arr => {
  return function(elem) {
    if (arr.includes(elem)) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
//
function notInArray(arr) {
  return function(elem) {
    if (arr.includes(elem)) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```